# Password reset link is not sending using Django. Even it's not showing any error but when I check my email, it's not showing any link here

Tags: django

I'm trying to send the password reset link to gmail but its not sending any link and even not showing any error.
How to solve it?

urls.py

```
path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="blog/password_reset.html"),
          name="reset_password"),
     path('reset_password_sent/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="blog/password_reset_sent.html"),
          name="password_reset_done"),
     path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="blog/password_reset_form.html"),
          name="password_reset_confirm"),
     path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="blog/password_reset_done.html"),
          name="password_reset_complete")
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_HOST_USER=''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=''
```

In EMAIL_HOST_USER I wrote my mail address and in EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD I wrote my password

Kindly help if anyone knows this issue.

Comment: I do not have any email.html and tokens.py . Kindly provide more about these.

Comment: Make sure that your [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#default-from-email) setting match your `EMAIL_HOST_USER` email address?

Comment: Note that there are lots of questions from other users finding it hard to use a Gmail account to send Django emails. It might be easier to use a different email provider

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. The problem was with my default email which I set for admin.